# apache httpd specify CipherSuite

Tags: apache-httpd, ssl

For some security reason, I need to use TLS1.2 protocol for my webapp. I can edit the httpd config file to choose ssl protocal and sslCipherSuite, but when I found that if I set sslCipherSuite to **HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5**, it would enable few set of CipherSuite.

Can I specify a sslCipherSuite for it, let say "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256" ??

My httpd version is  Apache/2.2.15

Thank you.

Comment: I saw a page (https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:Ciphers(1)) Is that mean, if I set "SSLCipherSuite AES128-SHA256" means TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to use TLS1.2 protocol for my webapp.

If you want to enforce TLS 1.2 you need to set the protocol version accordingly and not the cipher suites. The relevant option is SSLProtocol. To allow **only** TLSv1.2 use and forbid previous protocol versions use:

```
 SSLProtocol TLSv1.2
```

See the [official documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslprotocol)  for more details.

> Can I specify a sslCipherSuite for it, let say "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256" ??

To specify a cipher suite use the [SSLCipherSuite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslciphersuite) option. The syntax needs to include the cipher in a syntax which can be understood by OpenSSL, see [ciphers](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:Ciphers(1)#CIPHER_SUITE_NAMES) for more information. If you want to allow only this specific cipher use

```
SSLCipherSuite AES128-SHA256
```

Comment: Not exactly what I want, I can enable the TLSv1.2, but just want to specify a CipherSuite. My client site needs a particular encryption CipherSuite.

Comment: @JayAU: see updated answer.